# How do we find hybridization when molecule has resonance?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, resonance, hybridization

Consider the following image which shows the resonance structures of $\ce{CO_3^{2-}}$ ion. What is the hybridization of $\ce{O}$? How do we proceed in such cases? In one resonance structure, the top oxygen has $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridization and in others, it has $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridization. In the hybrid structure, shown in the second image, I don't even know how to proceed.

[image: resonance of carbonate]

[image: resonance hybrid of carbonate]

Comment: All the oxygens should be considered to be sp² hybridised, with its resonance-contibuting p orbitals being unhybridised and acting solely as pi-bonds.

Comment: @KanghunKim Not really, sp is an accurate description for, like, all terminal atoms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the hybridization of terminal fluorine atoms in molecules like boron trifluoride?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/what-is-the-hybridization-of-terminal-fluorine-atoms-in-molecules-like-boron-tri)

Comment: Boron trifluoride may seem different, but is isoelectronic with carbonate anion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only important thing to consider for the description in terms of hybridisation is the molecular structure. It is therefore irrelevant if you are using a resonance structure, all resonance structures, or the resonance hybrid, or even some kind of completely different diagram. The structure for all of these is the same.

Therefore, to determine a reasonable hybridisation scheme, you should first look at local coordination of the atom. Please keep in mind that the $x$ in $\mathrm{sp}^x$ doesn't need to be an integer value.
For this, please look up Bent's rule and Coulson's theorem. You may start with my answer here: [How is Bent's rule consistent with LCAO MO theory?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/139471/4945)
Please also keep then in mind that only orbitals hybridise and any combination of hybrid orbitals my be a valid description.<sup>*</sup>

If you keep this in mind, the following definition makes quite a bit more sense, hybridization in the Gold Book (DOI: [10.1351/goldbook.H02874](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.H02874))

> Linear combination of atomic orbitals on an atom. Hybrid orbitals are often used in organic chemistry to describe the bonding molecules containing tetrahedral (sp³), trigonal (sp²) and digonal (sp) atoms.

Considering this, here are some zero order approximations, which my come in handy:

| Coordination | Examples | Approximate Hybrid Orbital |
| --- | --- | --- |
| linear | carbon in acetylene or carbon dioxide, or any terminal atom<sup>**</sup> | sp |
| trigonal | carbon in $\ce{CO3^2-}$, boron in $\ce{BH3}$, carbon in acetone | sp² |
| tetrahedral | carbon in methane, sulfur in $\ce{SO4^2-}$ | sp³ |
| bent | oxygen in water | sp² - sp³ |
| trigonal pyramidal | nitrogen in ammonia | close to sp³ |
| trigonal bipyramidal | phosphorus in $\ce{PCl5}$ | model breaks down |
| octahedral | sulfur in $\ce{SF6}$ | model breaks down |

After writing all this, I've realised that I have commented on this before: [What is the hybridization of the carbonyl oxygen in a carboxylic acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/29255/4945)

---

**Footnotes:**

<sup>*</sup> The terminology we use for hybridisation actually is just an abbreviation:
$$\mathrm{sp}^x = \mathrm{s}^\frac{1}{x+1}\mathrm{p}^\frac{x}{x+1}$$
In theory $x$ can have any value; since it is just a unitary transformation, the representation does not change, hence
\begin{align}
 1\times\mathrm{s}, 3\times\mathrm{p} 
   &\leadsto 4\times\mathrm{sp}^3 \\
   &\leadsto 3\times\mathrm{sp}^2, 1\times\mathrm{p} \\
   &\leadsto 2\times\mathrm{sp}, 2\times\mathrm{p} \\
   &\leadsto 2\times\mathrm{sp}^3, 1\times\mathrm{sp}, 1\times\mathrm{p} \\
   &\leadsto \text{etc. pp.}\\
   &\leadsto 2\times\mathrm{sp}^4, 1\times\mathrm{p}, 1\times\mathrm{sp}^{(2/3)}
\end{align}

There are virtually infinite possibilities of combination.

Or see more: [Are the lone pairs in water equivalent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/50921/4945)

<sup>**</sup> I have written about this a few times already. These should provide also data:

- [What is the hybridization of terminal fluorine atoms in molecules like boron trifluoride?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/80965/4945)
- [What is the hybridization of chlorine in vinyl chloride?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/76954/4945)
- [Hybridisation of terminal nitrogen in diazomethane](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/66212/4945)