# Carbon dioxide electronic geometry

Tags: quantum-chemistry, stereochemistry, orbitals

It is known that allene (propadiene) $\ce{H2C=C=CH2}$ geometry is such that its hydrogen atoms are not in the same plane – do not form rectangle, but “extended tetrahedron”

[image: allene structure]

I wonder if structurally analogous carbon dioxide $\ce{O=C=O}$ exhibit similar geometry, i.e. do its lone electron pair orbitals form extended tetrahedron as well (IUPAC officers probably would not like following structure diagram)

[image]

or are they in the same plane? And why?

Comment: AFAIK, neither. Oxygens are probably sp hybridised - this stuff with el. pairs is tricky.

Comment: @Mithoron Well, what's then your proposal of its Lewis formula? I bet they are sp² hybridized, like in oxo group in organics.

Comment: It has nothing  to do with Lewis formula. You assume lone pairs have to be identical, but it's not true. Martin could elaborate more about this stuff.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50906/are-the-lone-pairs-in-water-equivalent

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76908/what-is-the-hybridization-of-chlorine-in-vinyl-chloride https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/what-is-the-hybridization-of-terminal-fluorine-atoms-in-molecules-like-boron-tri