# Does this general hybridization rule really apply?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

So this rule is known about hybridization that:
if 4 groups (atoms/pairs of electrons) are attached to the atom -> sp3
if 3 -> sp2
if 2 -> sp

but isn't that true only to specific elements only like carbon/oxygen/nitrogen..?

If you take CCl4, C is sp3, but chlorine has 4 groups around it but it's still not sp3 nor hybridized, it's just an sp3-p bond.

Even for nitrogen like in pyrrole, nirogen has 4 groups around it but it's sp2 because of resonance.

but can someone make it clear? to which elements does that rule apply? what elements undergo hybridization? what elements can they ask about in college regarding that?

Thank you

Comment: It basically works for carbon. Even O and N have a number of exceptions.

Comment: This rule is valid for atoms which are in the center of a molecule like Carbon in $\ce{CCl4}$ , and not for outer atoms like here Chlorine in $\ce{CCl4}$.

Comment: what should i do about outer atoms? i mean nitrogen can be outer atom or chlorine... for instance in
H-CN, it's S-SP-SP

Comment: In the case of HCN, well, H is the easy one; it has nothing to hybridise. C follows the standard rules. In this case, N behaves much like C. It needs to form two π bonds, which means that it needs to have two p orbitals; that's only possible if it is sp-hybridised. The rule *works* here, but you already know there are a number of exceptions, mainly because of resonance effects. For things like halogens, I'd suggest to throw this out of the window, as whatever it predicts can be refuted by more sophisticated theories (see e.g. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/76954/16683).