# Why is the bond angle of N-N-N in hydrogen azide not 180 degrees?

Tags: molecular-structure

Chen and Wang (2009) have reported an $\ce {N-N-N}$ bond angle in the hydrazoic acid molecule of $171.5$ degrees using B3LYP/6-311G** model. The wikipedia page for the molecule also reports a similar bond angle of $171$ degrees. However, this seems to go against predictions by VSEPR theory for the case of two regions of electron density (which gives a bond angle prediction of $180$ degrees). It is known that VSEPR theory is limited in its theoretical predictions. However, I would like to understand what accounts for the discrepancy in the two.

**Reference**

Chen, F., & Wang, F. (2009). Electronic Structure of the Azide Group in 3′-Azido-3′- deoxythymidine (AZT) Compared to Small Azide Compounds. Molecules, 14, 2656-2668. doi:10.3390/molecules14072656

Comment: Also relevant paper on the recent SCXRD investigation ([DOI: 10.1021/ja2027053](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja2027053)) suggests somewhat higher average $\ce{N-N-N}$ angle 172.8°. Besides, all 3 N atoms and both bonds in $\ce{N3}$ are quite inequivalent, so there is no wonder the angle is not 180°.

Comment: VSEPR doesn't predict anything.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19904/what-is-the-hybridization-of-the-nitrogen-in-the-azide-ion

Comment: https://acs.figshare.com/articles/dataset/Molecular_Structure_of_Hydrazoic_Acid_with_Hydrogen_Bonded_Tetramers_in_Nearly_Planar_Layers/2624300/1     Molecular Structure of Hydrazoic Acid with Hydrogen-Bonded Tetramers in Nearly Planar Layers